# Почему не работает longpoll?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть код но при запуске тупо ничего не происходит просто работает бесконечно, в чем может быть причина? (P.s Да я отправляю сообщения боту и на хостинге Heroku тоже не работает)

```
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

token = 'тут токен'
g_id = 'id группы'

vk_session = VkApi(token=token)
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, g_id)
vk = vk_session.get_api()


while True:
    try:
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                print(event)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

Comment: Гениальный хендлинг ошибок

Comment: Может быть ты не включил лонгпол в настройках сообщества? Или не включил событие входящего сообщения? (https://i.imgur.com/sAJ0ES6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте через `requests`.
Лично я не доверяю лонгполам либры.

```
server = self.vk.method('messages.getLongPollServer')
while True:
     data = json.loads(requests.get(
         'https://{server}?act=a_check&key={key}&ts={ts}&wait=25&mode=2&version=2'.format(
             server=server['server'],
             key=server['key'],
             ts=server['ts'])).text)
     if data.get('failed'):
          # ...

     if data.get('updates'):
          # ...
```